# How to convert dbm(database file) of Dos to Csv?

Tags: c++, database, dos

I have many file of from an application of Dos of the following types:

*.DBM
*.CFM
*.DBA
*.DBI
*.DBR
*.DBT
*.DBF

I think DBM is a database file.
Please help me to convert these database file to Csv format.

Comment: Possibly `dBase`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase#File_formats

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote a generator for decryption of DBM database file.
I understand that different code page is for this DB files,you must find code page that used for your DB and then you write decryption on code page of your DB files.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the generator you wrote so this answer will help future visitors with the same problem?